# How to distribute your own data on Salesforce?

Tags: api, community

I will work on a new project related to salesforce. Actually what we want to do is to have a salesforce API that contains our database and this API will accept connections from our clients. Once we establish the connection the user will have the access to our database too. Since I dont know anything about salesforce right now, I just wanted to ask you if you have some ideas on how to do that ? Is there any existing API doing that ? or We need to implement our new API for salesforce ?

Comment: Do you mean you wanna a have a customer portal where users come and access your SF data which is exposed to them?

Comment: yeah exactly I meant that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below to set up and configure your organization’s Salesforce Customer Portal.

1. Enable Your Customer Portal
2. Enabling Customer Portal Login and Settings
3. Customize Your Customer Portal Fonts and Colors
4. Customize Your Customer Portal Tabs
5. Customize Your Customer Portal Pages
6. Review Setup Tips and Considerations for Customer Portal Pages
7. Customize List Views
8. Customize Search Layouts
9. Set up Case Assignment Rules
10. Create Workflow Alerts
11. Configure User Access to the Customer Portal
12. Grant High-Volume Portal Users Access to Objects’ Records
13. Share Records Owned by High-Volume Portal Users to Salesforce Users
14. Enable Your Customer Portal for User Login
15. Add the Customer Portal URL to Your Organization’s Website
16. Enable Contacts and Person Accounts to Use Your Customer Portal

These steps are mentioned in details in this [document](http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf), I highly recommend you reading this or or [setting up your customer portal](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_setting_up.htm&language=en_US) article before enabling **Customer portal** on your organization.